# Reshaping two-column data using pandas pivot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot

I am trying to reshape a long text file with two columns (a repeating date_time sequence and a single column of numerical values) into a Pandas dataframe with a single index of date_time and multiple columns of data. The actual file is 100 sets of 82 years of daily rainfall data (from a stochastic generator) and is some 3 million lines. I want to have 100 columns of rainfall data against the 82 x 365(366 leap year) date_time index. To simplify the exercise I present an example below (the four-row sequence representing a leap-year):

```
2014/01/01  1
2014/01/02  2
2014/01/03  3

2014/01/01  4
2014/01/02  5
2014/01/03  6
2014/01/04  7

2014/01/01  8
2014/01/02  9
2014/01/03  10
```

The desired output is something like:

```
              0    1    2
2014/01/01    1    4    8
2014/01/02    2    5    9
2014/01/03    3    6    10
2014/01/04    nan  7    nan
```

This seems excruciatingly simple but it has me beat. I have tried to turn the original series into a dataframe, then use the following but Pandas does not seem to like a single column:

```
df.pivot()
```

Comment: Is each set of the same size? Or is the starting date always the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should first create a new column that indicates in which column the value has to come.

Supposing you know the starting date of each sequence (and it is the same each time), you can e.g. do that like this:

```
In [7]: df['set'] = (df['date'] ==  '2014/01/01').cumsum()

In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
         date  value  set
0  2014/01/01      1    1
1  2014/01/02      2    1
2  2014/01/03      3    1
3  2014/01/01      4    2
4  2014/01/02      5    2
5  2014/01/03      6    2
6  2014/01/04      7    2
7  2014/01/01      8    3
8  2014/01/02      9    3
9  2014/01/03     10    3
```

When you have this column, you can use `pivot`:

```
In [9]: df.pivot(index='date', columns='set', values='value')
Out[9]: 
set          1  2   3
date                 
2014/01/01   1  4   8
2014/01/02   2  5   9
2014/01/03   3  6  10
2014/01/04 NaN  7 NaN
```

---

EDIT: Thanks to DSM, another way to find the groups (and one where you don't have to know the first item of each group):

```
In [10]: df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

In [11]: df['set'] = (df['date'].diff().fillna(0) <= 0).cumsum()
```

This is based on the fact that when a new set starts, the time difference with the previous row will be negative (if the data is sorted by time).

Comment: Wow-- I was writing an answer myself, and the first sentence was "If you build a column containing a group id, so it knows which column something belongs to.." and then yours was posted. :^)  The only difference was that I converted the date column to a datetime and then used `(df[0].diff().fillna(0) <= 0).cumsum()` to find the groups.

Comment: @DSM Ah, but that may be a more robust way to find the different sets. I will add that!

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks both of you. I couldn't see how to add that column. I will now have to work out why that works!

Comment: @user2989613: the trick is that you want to get a value of True where every group starts.  True has an integer value of 1, so if you take the cumulative sum of `[True, False, False, True, False, False]`, you get `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]`.  (You can subtract 1 if you prefer things to start at 0.)

Comment: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Comment: @DSM I get this error when trying to apply. why might this be?

Comment: When do you get this exactly?

Comment: date = ['2014-01-01' , '2014-01-02', '2014-01-03', '2014-01-01' , '2014-01-02', '2014-01-03', '2014-01-04', '2014-01-01' , '2014-01-02', '2014-01-03']
values = np.random.normal(10, 2, len(date))
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':values, 'date': date})
df
# Suggested method to add a category or set column to the data to allow pivoting
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['set'] = (df['date'].diff() < 0).cumsum()  #counts each jump back to the first date (-ve diff = True = 1)
df.pivot(index='date', columns='set', values='value')

Comment: when I entered the above

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? With 0.13.1 the above code works without error. And do you get this with the last step (the pivot)?

Comment: @joris When I entered the above (sorry for the format)

Comment: @joris Sorry didn't see that reply. Looks like I have pandas 0.12. I will upgrade and see how we go. It was the second to last step Thanks again.

Comment: It's indeed a strange error in 0.12. If you can't upgrade, using `(df['date'].diff() < 0).astype(int).cumsum()` solves it for me.